Stop when one future task has completed in java
I have 2 FutureTask Objects.
My tasks are running parallelly.
However, What I want is that as soon as one of the FutureTask method completes its execution/job the other should stop. But inside method(method1() /method2()) how can I stop that?
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            
            //task 1
            Future future1 = executor.submit(new Callable() {
                @Override
                public Response call() throws Exception {
                    return method1();
                }
            });
            //task 2
            Future future2 = executor.submit(new Callable() {
                @Override
                public Response call() throws Exception {
                    return method2();
                }
            });
            Response response1 = (Response) future1.get();
            Response response2 = (Response)future2.get();
            executor.shutdown();
            if(response1!=null || response2.getMsg()!=null){
                System.out.println(response2.getMsg());
            }else{
                System.out.println("error");

            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //first method
    private static Response method1() {
        Response response=new Response();
        response.setMsg("test1"); //  ==> this might take long time
        return response;
    }
    //second method
    private static Response method2() {
        Response response=new Response();
        response.setMsg("test1"); //  ==> this might take long time
        return response;
    }

}

class Response {
    String msg;

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}

Can anyone help me to understand this?

Side note: Using newSingleThreadExecutor() in your scenario does not make sense. That will cause submitted tasks to execute one after the other sequentially, but you seem to want multiple tasks to execute in parallel.

See StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnSuccess in JEP 480: Structured Concurrency (Third Preview). Related presentations available at YouTube.

Unfortunately StructuredTaskScope is still in preview mode in Java 22, will continue to be so in Java 23, and nothing can be said about Java 24 yet (see https://openjdk.org/jeps/0). But yes, that would be the best tool for the job.
